# how can i get the page_ID in nav li

Tags: menus, pages, navigation, walker, id

I need a menu with the page IDs of the linked Pages in the li Tags.
It should look like that:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="pageid_23"><a href="page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li class="pageid_12"><a href="page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li class="pageid_41"><a href="page3">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have found many examples but not only one works (for me).

The best Article with exactly my Problem was Antonios:
http://webtonio.com/wordpress-adding-page-ids-to-menu/

But i only get Errors.
Maybe i paste the code in wrong places?

I use WP4.3 and 2015 Template.

Here ist how i tried it:

**functions.php**

```
    class nav_page_id extends Walker_Nav_Menu{  
        /**
         *      Walker object, appends page id to data-url attribute on link
         */
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {

           global $wp_query;

           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item-->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $output .= $indent . '

';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item>attr_title )   ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item>attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item>target ) ? ' target="'  . esc_attr( $item>target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item>xfn )  ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item>xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item>url ) ? ' href="'  . esc_attr( $item>url        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item>object_id )    ? ' data-id="' . esc_attr( $item>object_id )  .'"' : '';
           $item_output = $args->before;
           $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
           $item_output .= $args->link_before .apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item>ID );
           $item_output .= $args->link_after;
           $item_output .= '</a>';
           $item_output .= $args->after;

           $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );


                }


}
```

And thats the Error Message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>', expecting ')' in htdocs\test-wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen\functions.php on
>   line 354

line 354 is this one:

```
$attributes  = ! empty( $item>attr_title )   ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item>attr_title ) .'"' : '';
```

can You help me please?

Comment: `$item>attr_title` is not a valid expression to be used as parameter for `empty()` and `esc_attr( )` funtions. The error message says it all. are not valid PHP expressions. See docuemntation of [empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) and [esc_attr()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr) functions to find the correct syntax and accepted arguments of each one. And please, note that [PHP syntax errors are, in general, off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Can you not see it? This:

```
esc_attr( $item>attr_title )
```

...should be:

```
esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) // See the hyphen?
```